# Python 3 unittest - Is it possible to get access to assert information without overloading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I am building custom `TestResult` and TestRunner classes. I would like to capture assert information from every assert that is ran, regardless if it results in a Fail, Error, or Pass.

An example test scenario:

```
import unittest


class TestMath(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_square(self):
        self.assertEqual(9, 3*3)  # will Pass
        self.assertEqual(9, 3**3)  # will Fail
```

From running the above case, is it possible for me to access information such as assertion type, status, parameters, etc without digging into and overloading the assert methods with my own `TestCase`?

My end goal is to create something like this:

```
"TestMath": {
    "test_square": [
        {
            "type": "assertEqual",
            "status": "Pass",
            "expected": 9,
            "result": 9
        },
        {
            "type": "assertEqual",
            "status": "Fail",
            "expected": 9,
            "result": 27
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a built-in mechanism to get access to this kind of information that I am just not aware of? Or is this something I will need to address for my use case?